# Duplicate script for google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**DONE !!!**
Thanks a lot to Ilya Lapitan, and my friend Zent. You save me :)
What script to do:

- duplicate template sheet;
- rename new sheet like: **"Number" + "name from base sheet"** (its "All_base", where's list of names)

  ```
  function makeCopies() {
      ///getting active spreadsheet
      var activeSreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var basicSheet = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("All_base");
      var activeSreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var templateSheet = activeSreadsheet2.getSheetByName("1. Win");

      //setting template sheet as active
      activeSreadsheet2.setActiveSheet(templateSheet);

      //getting values from selected range
      var rangeArr = basicSheet.getRange("B4:B6").getValues();

      //going through range values
      for(i = 0; i < rangeArr.length; i++){

      //preparing name for new sheet
      var name = (i + 2) + '. ' + rangeArr[i][0];

      //making duplicate of base sheet
      var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();

      //setting new name for duplicated sheet
      newSheet.setName(name)
      }
  };
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution for making duplicates of base sheet by selected range:

```
function onOpen() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var entries = [{
     name : "Make Copies",
     functionName : "makeCopies"
   }];
   spreadsheet.addMenu("Duplicate", entries);
};

function makeCopies() {
   //getting active spreadsheet
   var activeSreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   //getting basic sheet
   var basicSheet = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("All_base");
   //setting basic sheet as active
   activeSreadsheet.setActiveSheet(basicSheet);
   //getting values from selected range
   var range = basicSheet.getRange("D7").getValue().split(", ");
   //going through range values
   for(i = 0; i < range.length; i++){
      //preparing name for new sheet
      var name = (i + 1) + '.' + range[i];
      //making duplicate of base sheet
      var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
      //setting new name for duplicated sheet
      newSheet.setName(name)
   }
 };
```

Example of using:

1. Select a range from base sheet
2. Select a menu item: "Duplicate" -> "Make Copies"

Comment: Thank you for answer!! But its create copy of basic list, where i have just column of names.. In other sheet I have template of sheet, that i want to duplicate (it has some tables, formulas), and the names of new sheet must taken from base sheet "All_base". Also, this script create new sheet with name: "name_from range"+sheet name(in my ex. All_base) it looks like: WindowsAll_base, RoomsAll_base .. etc, but i need this: 1. Window, 2. Rooms .. etc.

Comment: Twil, I've modified script. I suppose that all names for new sheet located in "D7" cell of "All_base" sheet. Also, I suppose that names are separated by comma. I hope,the news script will be more helpful for you.

Comment: Superb! Its almost what i want to do! Im update question, add your code, with changes that i try to explain. But this script doesnt work correct. He's create duplicate with name from D7 by each charecter like that: First list"1. W", second list "2. i,", third  "3. n", "4. d" and etc all word Window.. but need to create full names from range D7:D343, its create only from D7, separating this word by each character.  -

Comment: How it looks like http://prntscr.com/5vzr7c , also, number of sheet add to list descending: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, but need ascending: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5